# Get the explicit type of a generic parameter at runtime in Scala

Tags: scala

Note - this post references Spark, but doesn't necessarily need to - it can apply to anything requiring a type parameter, (e.g. `case class MyThing[T](t:T)`)

I'm trying to determine what the runtime class is of a generic parameter, specifically within a Dataset, in order to grok a useful error message, I'm trying to do something like:

```
def killIfEmpty[T](ds:Dataset[T])(implicit sparkSession:SparkSession):Unit = {
if (ds.head(1).isEmpty) {
  throw new Exception(s"Dataset[${
    ds.getClass.getSimpleName
  }] had zero rows.")
}
```

}

But unfortunately, this doesn't show anything useful, calling

```
val spark:SparkSession = ???
val emptyDs:Dataset[String] = ???
killIfEmpty[Dataset[String]](emptyDs)
```

I'm expecting this to print a message that says:

> Dataset[String] had zero rows.

But what happens is it results in :

> Dataset[Dataset] had zero rows.

Does anyone know how to get the actual class name from the generic parameter?

Comment: Shouldn't it be just `dsClass.getSimpleName`?

Comment: @Kombajnzbożowy, unfortunately that just returns `org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it, I need to work with `TypeTag`

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

def killIfEmpty[T : TypeTag](ds:Dataset[T])(implicit sparkSession:SparkSession):Unit = {
    if (ds.head(1).isEmpty) {
      throw new Exception(s"Dataset[${
        datasetBaseClassName(typeTag[T])
      }] had zero rows.")
    }
  }

  private def datasetBaseClassName[T : TypeTag]: String = {
    typeOf[T].typeSymbol.name.toString
  }
```

Providing the context bound `[T : TypeTag]` on the method declaration allows me to call these functions without explicitly needing to provide the tag. See the doc on [context bounds](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/context-bounds.html) to learn more.

I would think there's a way to do this without defining that same context bound on the publically available `killIfEmpty` function, but I am not sure - I'm open to correction!

Comment: 1. Just `datasetBaseClassName[T]` instead of `datasetBaseClassName(typeTag[T])` should work as well. 2. "I would think there's a way to do this without defining that same context bound on the publically available killIfEmpty function" No, I don't think so.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov, 1. indeed works, thank you. 2. Noted, c'est la vie.